# Establishing mutual authentication over SSH using SPIFFE

Tags: ssh, azure, kubernetes, authentication, x509

For this learning purpose I have created a k8s cluster using 4 azure VMs (VM1, VM2, VM3 & VM4).I have followed the spiffe doc to deploy spire-server and spire-agent on a k8s infra. I have kept all the default configurations that are given in the doc.

I want to understand how can i register the SSH process as a workload and use it to perform SSH to my VMs in the cluster instead of using the default private key given by azure to login through ssh.

I have gone through the doc but couldn't find a proper solution for it, any help is highly appreciated.